# Share session between Core Php & CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a web app which is in **Core PhP**. And we are moving it to **CI Framework** step by step.

**Problem:** Need to share session value between them.

**Core PHP App Dir Structure:**`|-- /xampp/lms/`
**Core PHP App URL:**  `http://localhost/`**lms**`/index.php`

**CI App Dir Structure:**  `|-- /xampp/lms/newlms/`
**CI App URL:**  `http://localhost/lms/`**newlms**`/index.php/login`

**CI Configuration:**

```
config.php

$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

**What I have did so far.**

**Core PHP changes**
Path: `\xampp\htdocs\lms\configuration.inc.php` (*this is file  called first in core php*)

```
session_name('ci_session');
session_start();

echo '<pre>';
echo '<br/>------------- session_save_path-------- <br/>';
print_r(session_save_path());
echo '<br/>------------- session_name-------- <br/>';
print_r(session_name());
echo '<br/>------------- $_COOKIE -------- <br/>';
print_r($_COOKIE);
echo '<br/>------------- $_SESSION -------- <br/>';
print_r($_SESSION);
exit;
```

**output:**

```
------------- session_save_path-------- 
\xampp\tmp
------------- session_name-------- 
ci_session
------------- $_COOKIE -------- 
Array (
    [ci_session] => 2b9tj8rek53kapgsuh4k3v2fuuvblvq9
)

------------- $_SESSION -------- 
Array (
    some values which I have set in Core php
)
```

Session Path `xampp\tmp\sess_2b9tj8rek53kapgsuh4k3v2fuuvblvq9`

**CI changes**
path: `\xampp\htdocs\lms\newlms\application\modules\login\controllers`

```
Class Login extends MX_Controller {

   function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
   }

   function index() {
echo '<pre>';
echo '<br/>------------- session_save_path-------- <br/>';
print_r(session_save_path());
echo '<br/>------------- session_name-------- <br/>';
print_r(session_name());
echo '<br/>------------- $_COOKIE -------- <br/>';
print_r($_COOKIE);
echo '<br/>------------- $_SESSION -------- <br/>';
print_r($_SESSION);
exit;
   }
 }
```

**output:**

```
------------- session_save_path-------- 
\xampp\tmp
------------- session_name-------- 
ci_session
------------- $_COOKIE -------- 
Array (
    [ci_session] => 2b9tj8rek53kapgsuh4k3v2fuuvblvq9
)

------------- Core $_SESSION -------- 
Array (
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1479978675
)

------------- CI $_SESSION -------- 
CI_Session Object (
 .. Some values.
)
```

**PS:** I have tried to explain in best way but Before **Down Voting** please share the reason.

Comment: What version of CI are you using? CI's session handler is just a wrapper of the php session handler

Comment: @bertmaclin CI's version = 3.1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by bertmaclin,

> CI's session handler is just a wrapper of the php session handler

Have tweek CI's config.php & session Library.

**CI config.php:**  added given code just before **`base_url`** configuration.

```
session_start();
```

**CI Session.php:**  added @ before **`session_start()`** in session library line #142.

```
@session_start();
```

Comment: This really worked for me, TYSM. You saved my day.